# Which solution should I pick for scalable frequent read / write of public geolocation data over HTTP?

Tags: redis, apache-kafka, geolocation, rabbitmq, geospatial

I am designing an application where users can agree to share their geolocation (lat, lng) between any other user in specific range.

This mean that if there are 100 users that actively use the application in X-radius, every N-seconds they update their location data and share them with each other.

In other words, a realtime app would mean that 1 write = 100 reads, and 100 writes equals to 10000 reads.

Probably one thing from a software side that I can do is to manipulate the write / read interval to reduce the load burst (at best spread it evenly).

But there comes another thing which is a scalable solution with **geoquering** ability.

What I tried was a Firestore but the payment model didn't fit, I need a fixed-price solution.

I have been considering a message broker like Kafka or RabbitMQ, but I am not sure if they support the geoqueries.

Right now I am looking at Redis and PostGIS, I should also consider the way I return the data over HTTP request / response.

Since the data will always be public (when the user agree), there is no any authorization overhead so I am looking for simplest, fastest solutions.

I will appreciate any tips where to go with that

Comment: Message queues don't support "queries" at all without external tooling

Comment: You're going to have to write custom code for this at some level. A project I work on basically wrote its own message broker to handle geospatial "interest" in update events. Alternatively, you may be able to create a custom exchange type for RabbitMQ, but I don't know how involved that would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your application is write and read heavy. Better to approach with a in memory solution. From this point you can use [Redis|GEORADIUS](https://redis.io/commands/GEORADIUS). Redis has builtin geo-location search. And also capable of handling millions of read-write with minimal resource requirement.

Comment: This confirms my thoughts, I think that this should be enough. Take my accept